# The Predators have a signature 'deboning' move that is admittedly dramatic but seems implausible. Has it ever been commented on?

Tags: predator-series, predator

This spectacular move is depicted at least 3 times in the various Predator films; 'Predator' (Billy Sole), 'Predator 2' (Jerry Lambert) and 'Predators' (Stans). I can't find any clearly supporting data that such a technique could be plausible given the human anatomy.

Has there been any commentary either canon or non-canon that could explain such an amazing feat?

Comment: If we assume high technology, nearly anything is possible. Even with our own, there are a variety of specialty filet and deboning tools that can do what seems unlikely. All it would require is a few seconds not depicted in the film, using such a knife/tool/whatever.

Comment: “there are a variety of specialty filet and deboning tool” — debonulators, if you will.

Comment: It does seem sort of implausible, given their superhuman strength, that they could perform such a delicate and intricate procedure without destroying the carcass

Comment: They learned the technique from MK1 Sub-Zero. Source: me (non-canon ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Predators clearly had superior strength, speed, endurance and agility. The Predator could lift up Arnold with one arm and jump from tree to tree etc.

I would surmise that they have the strength to do this BUT I agree; being able to rip out the spine "cleanly" does seem unlikely.  And it probably would come out in pieces (not as a whole unit)

Maybe they break all the ribs first and make some cuts..?

And no, I've never seen an explanation of how they do it. Hey, can we ask Mythbusters to test this out?

Comment: I saw a photo of a nasty car crash couple of years ago.  Guy in a convertible (top down) smashed into the side of semi's trailer.  Car went underneath but his head didn't quite make it.  The photo's were gruesome.  Showed his now detached head with the spine still attached to it lying on the pavement.  I'll never forget that photo !!

Comment: (!!!) Maybe I shouldn't have gotten involved in this thread...

Comment: @Stan Links please!

Comment: @Matemáticos Chibchas Was in an email that someone sent me a couple of years and wasn't something I thought to save at the time.  Did find a [link](http://www.nypost.com/p/news/local/emts_are_pic_and_twisted_WHMpohpsktzM2epWfrXw9I) to a news story that references a pic like I saw (might be the same one).  No pics in the article though.

Comment: @Stan: there are many well documented cases (most recently of Saddam Hussein) where a botched hanging ripped the victim's head off. There are no reports that the spine came with it. I suspect the photo you received had been doctored.

Comment: @John Rennie Did you read the article I linked in the prior comment ?  I'm pretty certain the photo was not doctored. Strange stuff can happen to the body in accidents. And this thread is now getting weird :)  Sorry I added my initial comment.

Comment: “this thread is now getting weird” — nah, people can be way too sensitive. Anyway, whenever I’ve tried the Predator deboning move it *totally* hasn’t worked.